# Zeeman Effect, Fine structure and Spin-Orbit Coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy

I have a question about Spin-Orbit Coupling, Zeeman effect and Fine Structure. I'll try to explain what I don't understand and want to know as good as I possibly can. This here is a sketch of how I understand  orbital, intrinsic, and total angular momentum and their respective mangetic moments (and their components):

> For one electron of an atom: 
> **Orbital Angular Momentum** ($\vec{L}$) 
> $\vec{L}= \pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ L_z} $, $L_z$ is the $z$-component of $\vec{L}$ 
> Magnetic moment for $\vec{L}$: $\vec{\mu}_L = -\frac{e}{2m_e}\vec{L}$ $\implies \mu_{L_{z}} = -m_\ell g_\ell\mu_B$ 
>
> **Intrinsic Angular Momentum of Electron** ($\vec{S}$) 
> $\vec{S}= \pmatrix{S_x \\ S_y \\ S_z} $, $S_z$ is the $z$-component of $\vec{S}$ 
> Magnetic moment for $\vec{S}$: $\vec{\mu}_S = -\frac{e}{2m_e}\vec{S}$ $\implies \mu_{S_{z}} = -m_sg_s\mu_B$
>
> **Total Angular Momentum of Electron** ($\vec{J} = \vec{L}+\vec{S}$) 
> Magnetic moment for $\vec{J}$: $\vec{\mu}_J = -\frac{e}{2m_e}\vec{J}$ $\because g_s\approx2\implies\vec{\mu}_J\not\parallel\vec{J}$, but if we built its component along the axis of $\vec{J}$, we can write it as above 
> $J_z = L_z + S_z \implies$ magnetic component of the $z$-component of $\vec{J}$: $\mu_{J_{z}} = -m_jg_j\mu_B$

Now I have the following questions:

1. Consider $l=1$, we can find the magnitude of $\vec{L}$ (with the given formula which depends from the orbital quantum number $l$). This $\vec{L}$ that we find, I assume is the orbital angular momentum of an electron with let's say $n=2$, $l=1$, not the total orbital angular momentum of all the electrons up to this point.
2. Consider $l=1$, we have 3 different magnetic quantum numbers, which means that under the influence of an external magnetic field we can split the orbit $n=2$, $l=1$ in 3 additional orbitals? Is this the Zeeman effect?
3. Then what is the Fine Structure? Because for each value of $m_l$ for $l=1$, we have 2 electrons, each with spin $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$. This means that each of the 3 splittings will be split 2 more times additionally, for a total of 6 different splittings when both effects happen?
4. How does the the Zeeman effect applies to Spin-Orbit Coupling. As far as I can understand we can have the Spin Zeeman effect, the Orbital Zeeman effect and what I assume to be the spin-orbital Zeeman effect.
5. If we calculate the total orbital angular momentum of an atom (as the vector sum of the orbital angular momentum of each electron), and we do the same for the total spin of the atom; We can then find the total angular momentum of the atom. Does it serve us any purpose regarding Zeeman or Stark effect?

What I am trying to ask is: The Zeeman effect is "connected" with the different angular momentum and magnetic dipole moment of electron or the whole atom.

Once again sorry if what I am asking is badly constructed but it's the result of me not understanding the  different Zeeman effect's which can happen for different magnetic fields which can be constant or non-constant, the Stark effect and the Fine structure.

Can someone link me a picture of the splitting of the spectral lines when only fine structure occurs, or when only Zeeman effect occurs, or when both occur (if they do), Stark effect etc.

Comment: What is $m_J$ in your image?

Comment: mj is the magnetic quantum number for the total angular momentuml, mj= -j,-j+1,...+j where as j= |l +/- s|

Comment: it says that i must have at least 20 reputation points to chat there. but it would be fantastic if i could chat with someone, instead of waiting

Comment: Your question has been drastically edited for good and there are chances that some errors might have crept in while editing, please ensure that the question in its current form does not miss out or misinterpret the original image which you used. As a side note, using images is discouraged because of the loss of searchability in images, thus from now on, I strongly recommend you to **not use images**, rather type it out. Also, you might also not get the services of kind editors in future, so don't expect your image to be typesetted by someone else.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. How do i write all that stuff in here, is there a site for that?

Comment: It's called MathJax, there's an elaborate documentation [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).